# How to modify this regex so it doesn't match * * *

Tags: javascript, regex

```
(?<!\*)\*([^*]+?)\*(?!\*)/g
```

This is basically a regex to match Markdown italics. It will match the following situations:

```
This *is* Markdown.
This *is Markdown.*
*This* is *Markdown.*
*This is Markdown.*
```

Note: The negatives lookarounds are there to avoid matching cases like this one `This is **Markdown.**`

It works ... almost. It's also matching `* * *`, which I use as section breaks. Like this:

```
* * *

This *is* Markdown.

* * *
```

How to change my regex so it doesn't match these section breaks? I'm really stuck.

RegExr: https://regexr.com/4tv5n

Comment: You should probably be using a Markdown parser.

Comment: Removing the lookarounds from the beginning and end of the regex did not change how the regex matched on your examples (at least for me)

Comment: @VLAZ Well, I want to improve my regex skills. This one is too difficult for me, though.

Comment: `(?<!\*)\*([^ ][^*]*?)\*(?!\*)` this will help with example but will be bad if the good ones have spaces after `*`...

Comment: @nickb They are there to prevent matching `**bold text**`.

Comment: You can match  `* * *` so that it is not part of the markdown in the example data `\* \* \*|(?<!\*)\*([^*]+)\*(?!\*)`  https://regex101.com/r/i4bc5R/1 But I think it would be better to use a parser.

Comment: @Eraklon Oh, your regex seems to work. Even if there is a space after `*`: https://regexr.com/4tv5n. Maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: @alexchenco Okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may suffice `(?<!\*)\*([^ ][^*]*?)\*(?!\*)`. For the example at least.

Comment: I meant by that if in the good examples there is a space so like: This * is* Markdown. This is Markdown.

Comment: Oh, you're right. There *is* a problem: https://regexr.com/4tv5n.

Comment: `(?<!\*)\*([^ ][^*\n]*?)\*(?!\*)` this solve the multiline match. But still need the solve this space issue I guess.

Comment: Oh, this new regex matches everything perfectly. https://regexr.com/4tv8t. In which situations will it fail? You mean it won't match `This * is* Markdown`?

Comment: Yes, I mean that, altough that might invalid for Italic anyway? Im not sure about these stuff. regexr.com/4tv99

Comment: I consider it invalid italic, so your regex is fine. I'll just wait for a bit, then check it as correct answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://markdown-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#horizontal-rules) there are more valid horizontal rule combinations.

This one I think is simpler and better captures the essence of the rule :

```
\*(?!\s*\*)([^*\n]+)\*
```

It is also faster, as it takes [89 steps](https://regex101.com/r/38Lltz/3) instead of [204 steps](https://regex101.com/r/EZgANy/1).