# Modifying regex to match beginning and end characters

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and playing around with writing regex to match markdown syntaxes, particularly italic text like:

`this is markdown with some *italic text*`

After writing some naive implementations I [found this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151057/how-to-modify-this-regex-so-it-doesnt-match#comment106388712_60151281) which seems to do the job quite nicely (dealing with edge-cases) and matches the entire string:

`(?<!\*)\*([^ ][^*\n]*?)\*(?!\*)`

However, I don't want to match the entire string - I only want to match the beginning and end `*` characters (so that I can do some special formatting to those characters). How might I go about doing that?

The tricky thing is that I only want to the match the `*` characters when the rest of the string matches the correct format of a string in italics (i.e. meets the requirements of that regex above). So a simple regex like `(\*|\*)` isn't going to cut it.

Comment: The negated character class does not have to be non greedy. You can add an asterix to the first negated character class as well to prevent a double asterix to match as wel. `(?<!\*)\*([^*\s][^*\r\n]*)\*(?!\*)` See https://regex101.com/r/aYdJiX/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the first and second `\*` to capturing groups and you can change at will:

```
(?<!\*)(\*)([^ ][^*\n]*?)(\*)(?!\*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TMOiHj/3/)

Comment: Thanks so much, I am getting used to the regex syntax and the capture groups now make a lot more sense!

Comment: This also matches [double asterisk](https://regex101.com/r/TMOiHj/4)

Answer (score 2):

Except from using a capturing group for the asterix at the start and at the end, you can add an asterix to the first negated character class to prevent matching a double `**`.

**Note** that as pointed out by @[toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto) you don't really need the capturing groups around the asterix `(\*)`. You can also match them and add the replacement characters before and after the single capturing group for the content in the middle.

It also means that it should match at least a single character other then an asterix.

You don't have to make the first character class non greedy `*?` as it can not cross the `*` boundary that follows.

```
(?<!\*)(\*)([^*\s][^*\r\n]*)(\*)(?!\*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DB5rv0/1)

If there can also not be a space before the ending asterix, you can repeat matching a space followed by matching any non whitespace char except an asterix `(?: [^*\s]+)*`

The `\r\n` in the negated character class is to prevent newline boundaries which are also matched by `\s`. If that should not be the case, you can replace that by a space or tab and space.

```
(?<!\*)(\*)([^*\s]+(?: [^*\s]+)*)(\*)(?!\*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y2pTOb/1)

Comment: Nice, but IMHO the capture groups around `\*` are useless.

Comment: @toto I see what you mean, but this is in the question `The tricky thing is that I only want to the match the * characters`. You don't really need the groups here as if the pattern matches you can only use a single capturing group for the middle content and add the chars before and after.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @Thefourthbird, this is a great explanation!